# Calculate $\Gamma{(n)} \times \Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2}) $

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I want to prove that $$\Gamma{(n)} \times \Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}  \times \Gamma(\frac{n}{2}) \frac{\sec(\frac{n\pi}{2})}{2^{1-n}}$$

What i know is the duplication formula which is $$\sqrt{\pi} \ \Gamma{(2n)}  = \Gamma(n) \times \Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})2^{2n-1}$$

Comment: Use Euler’s Reflection formula.

Comment: How to use that? I am not getting anything in the direction of answer.

Comment: Your first identity stands no chance of being true. The LHS grows much faster than the RHS as $n\to +\infty$. Additionally, the LHS makes sense for any $n\in\mathbb{R}^+$, the RHS doesn't.